# Существуют ли отечественные облачные поставщики?

Tags: облако, облачное-хранилище

Отечественные в следующем смысле:

1. Головной центр и налоги платят в РФ
2. Более одного дата центра на территории РФ (например Москва, Салихард) соединенных внутренней, защищенной, быстрой сетью
3. Возможность динамически создавать (поднимать) и удалять (выключать) виртуальные машины (API)
4. Почасовая оплата за потребляемые мощности

Всякий азур и амазон в РФ ДЦ не предоставляет... а жаль.

Есть ли в России провайдеры предоставляющие такие услуги?

Comment: @Blender, Вас интересует сеть *не через интернет-провайдера* (т.е. собственные физические каналы)?

Если так, то сомневаюсь, что имеющие их организации в обозримое время займутся облачным бизнесом.

Comment: Ну кроме ФСБ и МО, конечно )) у них то точно есть свои каналы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

infoboxcloud? (в пределах россии, правда, всего один ДЦ)

upd там же нашелся список конкурентов

[image]
<sub>(источник: [scaleengine.net](http://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/1e572b015a22fe0d9dd8aac5cc58793c.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

вроде mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

Краем уха слышал от информированного чела, что Сбербанк готовится выйти на рынок облаков. По крайней мере дата центры у них дюже крутые. В частности [не самый новый на Южнопортовой](http://www.sberbank.ru/komi/ru/press_center/all/?id114=11024647) - всего полгода назад презентовали то ли в Самаре то ли в Нижнем дата центр.

Ну а от дата центра до облака - всего 1 шаг...